# Gitlab 6.2 email notifications sideckiq warn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, sidekiq

I've just installed Gitlab 6.2 on an ubuntu server and am now having issues with email notifications. GitLab does not send any emails of any kind.
In sidekiq.log I have something like this:

```
 'WARN: Couldn't find User with id=10'
```

Could it be the reason why Gitlab does not send emails?

Comment: This warning seems self explanatory. Could you check if the gitlab is connected to the very same database in which your users are stored?

Comment: It is the same database. I think there is a possibility that my problem actualy is this issue: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2747. But it has 'closed' status and my version is later. I dont know could this be the reason of my email problem or not.

Comment: Yep... But according to that thread, jobs will fail because of sidekiq's speed but will eventtually execute successfully. I think you are not able to get notifications at all?

Comment: Yep, there are no emails at all. But also no more other errors or warnings in app logs although I've set 'Gitlab::Application.config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
' in gitlab/gonfig/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.

Comment: this setting will be helpful if the app is having problem actually sending email. The problem you mention suggest that the mail functionality is not even being hit. Something is failing before that.

Comment: How can I find out where is the problem?

Comment: I don't have experience with gitlab setup and can therefore give you only general advice. If you are absolutely sure there is nothing wrong with your setup when start toying with gitlab versions to see if something works.